# Using Dart with HTML (things i could do in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-html

What I did in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function displayThesis(){
    var thesisForm = document.getElementById("thesisForm").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("activeForm").innerHTML = thesisForm;
}

function displayNonThesis(){
var nonThesisForm = document.getElementById("nonThesisForm").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("activeForm").innerHTML = nonThesisForm;
}
</script>
```

then later i would do something such as:

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <p>Do you need the thesis option form?</p>
  <label>Yes</label>
  <input name="thesisOption" type="radio" value="Yes" onclick="displayThesis()" />
  <label>No</label>
  <input name="thesisOption" type="radio" onclick="displayNonThesis()" />
 </form>
```

to call those functions.

How would i do this with an external dart program that is listed and called with:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="attempt1.dart"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's forbidden in Dart. Inline event listeners is bad idea anyway. It's much better to separate HTML and script code. You can attach event listeners from dart code:

```
document.query('input[name="thesisOption"][value="Yes"]').on.click.add( (e) {
  document.query("#activeForm").innerHTML = document.query("#thesisForm").innerHTML;
});
```

Of source, you should add significant class names and ids to elements to refer to them clearly.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how exactly to implement this. I can just leave this in my Main() and then how do i make it

    document.query("#activeForm").innerHTML = thesisForm;
?

Comment: Fixed my comment. But I'm not sure because I don't know dart syntax well.